# How to include AngularJS expression into div class string?

Tags: angularjs

For example:

```
<div class="chart-percentage">
    <span>{{data[0].percent}}</span>
    <div class="percentage-line width35 blue1"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of hard coding 'width35', is there a way to use class=" width+data[0].percent "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Angular 1.x version
```

Use `ng-class` for like below

```
<div class="percentage-line blue1" ng-class="'width' + data[0].percent"></div>
```

---

```
Angular 2.x and above
```

Use [class] one way binding (you can use es6 template literals (back ticks))

```
<div class="percentage-line blue1" [class]=`width${data[0].percent}`></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-class="'width' + data[0].percent"`